# Extern array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, structure, extern

I have a global array of structure declared as

```
struct _links link[255][255][255];
```

in my main.c. This array of structures is also used in another file, action.c, and I tried to declare it in action.c as an extern, i.e.

```
extern struct _links link[255][255][255];
```

However, I got the error message "array type has incomplete element type". I don't understand what that means. How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you include the file containing the definition of `_links` in the second file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your structure `struct _links` in a header file; include that in both my_main.c  and action.c, compile them seperately and link them.

It works without header file for in-built data types. but for user defined data types, header file is needed.

Comment: Note that the main reason for this is that the compiler can't know the size and alignment of the array elements in action.c without a complete definition of `struct _links`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a type `struct _links` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

a good programming practice is to create a new file links.h which contains

```
extern struct _links link[255][255][255];
```

include this file on both main.c and action.c .

do not forget to define the variable only once.

for more informations about extern keyword,take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/1117720